# Kensington VeriMark fingerprint reader stop working after reboot

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, biometrics, windows-hello

I purchased [Kensington VeriMark fingerprint reader](http://a.co/86N1rui) few day back for adding convince to sign in Windows and other website that use U2F. It first worked after the installation without reboot. Windows Hello can idenitify the device and guide me though the registering process. The login is blazing fast. However, after a reboot of the machine for changing the GPU, Windows Hello shutoff.

I tried to re-plug the reader, reinstall the device, connect it directly to the computer. All of this above don't work. In `Setting -> Account -> Sign-in option -> Windows Hello` show a sentence: "Windows Hello isn't available on this device." with a link that doesn't help at all.

I used W10Privacy and DoNotSpy10 to tweak the system so it won't show advertisement and collect excessive info for MS. I'm sure that I uncheck the biometric option.

Note: Device Manager can identify the reader and place it correctly under "Biometric devices" category.

What am I possible be missing? I have to return it if it can't get the job done.

**EDIT**: After a unsuccessful system restore, it seems Windows Hello shows up again. However, the root cause is not clear yet.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your VeriMark fingerprint reader from Device manager, delete its driver.

Download driver from Kensington official website.

Verimark_Driver_v5.5.3511.1066_x86-x64_Setup (Windows 7, Windows 8.1 , Windows 10)

https://www.kensington.com/us/us/7772/k67977ww/verimark-fingerprint-key

connect the Kensington VeriMark fingerprint reader to your machine, install downloaded software

check again.

Comment: I tried this already. I think there must be something wrong with either those piracy tweaking unities or Windows Hello. I don't think driver is causing the problem since Device Manager can identify it correctly.